# Calling stored procedure and passing parameter from another stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure that deletes rows according to array that was passed to it as XML parameter:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE @docHandle int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @XMLDoc

DELETE Comments WHERE 
       ID IN (SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@docHandle, '/values/value1', 2) WITH (value1 INT '.'))

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @docHandle
END
```

Now instead of DELETE i want to call to another stored procedure (that executes hierarchical delete, it receives ID parameter)

How can I do that?

**UPDATE:** this is my second SP:

```
(
    @ID int
)
AS
IF @ID<>1 
BEGIN   
    CREATE TABLE #nodesC (id int primary key)
    INSERT INTO  #nodesC (id) VALUES (@ID )

    WHILE @@rowcount > 0
        INSERT INTO #nodesC 
        SELECT child.ID  
        FROM Comments child
        INNER JOIN #nodesC parent ON child.ParentId = parent.id
        WHERE child.ID  NOT IN (SELECT id FROM #nodesC)

    DELETE
    FROM Comments
    WHERE ID  IN (SELECT id FROM #nodesC)

END
```

Comment: you would do it in exactly the same way?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass an array as a parameter directly. So:

- Pass in XML and parse in 2nd stored proc
- Use table datatype (SQL Server 2008)
- Multiple calls to 2nd stored proc per ID in parsed XML (bad, here for completeness)

Otherwise, the authoritative article on how do deal with this is [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) by Erland Sommarskog

Comment: yes, i want tocall  Multiple time  2nd stored proc per ID in parsed XML, why it's bad?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a cursor.

```
DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT ... FROM OPENXML(...) WITH(...)
OPEN c
WHILE 1 <> 0 BEGIN
    FETCH c INTO ...
    IF @@fetchstatus <> 0 BREAK
    EXEC ...
END
CLOSE c
DEALLOCATE c
```